# Libevent - causes an error at the very start

Tags: c, libevent

Please tell me: I connected the libvent to the project for Windows VS2019 and called only one function Libevent:

```
#include <event2/bufferevent.h>
#include <event2/buffer.h>
#include <event2/event.h>


int main(void)
{   
    struct event_base* Event_base = event_base_new();        
}
```

And immediately got the error:

```
[warn] evsig_init_: socketpair: Either the application did not invoke WSAStartup, or an error occurred in WSAStartup.
```

That is, i understand that the point is that you need to initialize the Winsosk library Windows and call the WSAstartup() function, but shouldn't Libevent himself do this internally?

Comment: WSAstartup should only be called once per application.  If every library called it, that would obviously fail.

Comment: @stark, thanks now it became clear.